# WIX: How to set the version found after FindRelatedProducts in the Install UI Sequence

Tags: wix, upgrade

I am creating a WIX installer with upgrade functions. Here is our target: we want the installer informs the user that it finds a related product by outputting the version number of the found one in installer UI. And only after the user confirms this upgrade the installation will go on. However, I don't know how to set a property (or variable), to be displayed in a dialog UI. Currently I have already added one confirm dialog which has the condition "NOT Installed AND UPGRADEFOUND". I just need to put the version number string into this dialog. Can anyone tell me how to do that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here. You can either use the [FileSearch](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/check_the_version_number.htm) element to get the version stored in the main binary of your application or you can store the version in the registry using the [remember property pattern](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/5/2/The-WiX-toolsets-Remember-Property-pattern) on install and then re-read that when you upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'll read it. I think this remember property pattern is especially useful. Even though currently I just use a custom action to search the registry, by product code which is set to UPGRADEFOUND by FindRelatedProducts action.